# Proof of Baire category theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm whatching the proof of the Baire category theorem, which says:

Thm.
Every complete metric space is of second category.

Now, on my notes, the proof is done by contradiction, assuming that X is a Banach space and $$ X=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}C_n , \ \ C_n \text{ closed nowhere dense}$$
I've understood the proof, the only problem is that it assumes that the $C_n $ are closed, while in the definition of first category set, the sets are not necessarily closed. Hence the proof is not completely general. I'm trying to generalize this. So suppose:$$X=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n , \ E_n \text{ nowhere dense}$$
Since $X$ is both open and closed, then $X= \overline{X} $. Hence $X=\overline{\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\overline{E_n}$. Clearly $\overline{E_n}$ is nowhere dense, so I can use the proof of the theorem. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
$$
\overline{\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\overline{E_n}
$$
is in general wrong (example, each $E_n$ is a singleton of a rational number).

But we do have
$$
\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\overline{E_n} \supseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n = X
$$
so your argument is close.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you!